# html form jquery validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, plugins

I have been trying for a long time but I can't figure how to get jquery validation plugin working with HTML, I would really appreciate your help.
I guess it is something trivial but I can't find a solution.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="forma">
            <p>
                <label for="username" id="labelusername">usename</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            </p>
            <input type="submit" id="save" value="submit" onclick="" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        $().ready(function(){
            $("#forma").validate({
                rules: {
                    username: "required"
                },

                messages:
                {
                    username: "please enter"
                }
            });
        });
</script>  
</html>
```

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: did you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to coding.

Here i noticed that, you are missing jquery document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

     <form  id="forma">

                  <p>
                      <label for="username" id="labelusername">usename</label>
                      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  />

                  </p>


                  <input type="submit" id="save" value="submit" onclick="" />                        

              </form>


</body>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){

        $("#forma").validate({


        rules:
        {

        username:"required"

        },


        messages:
        {
        username:"please enter"
    }

    });

});


</script>

</html>
```